# I cannot update a textarea using PHP update

Tags: php, mysql

What im trying to do is to present the text in the 'text' row of the table about in a textarea... (that was a strange sentence)
and i should be able to add/remove/edit text in that textarea and then press save to update it...

When trying the about table gets wiped of all data...

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit_about']))

{

mysql_query("UPDATE about SET `text` = '$row['text']'");

}

// get result from database
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM about") 
    or die(mysql_error());

// present the result
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

  echo "<form method='post' action='uc_admin.php'>
  <textarea name='text' rows='8'>" . $row['text'] . "</textarea>
  <br />
  <button type='submit' name='submit_about' class='btn'>Save</button>";
}

?>
```

Comment: your query should use $_POST['text'] not $row, and there are security data sanitation issues here.

Comment: And you really should sanitize the input. I'm sure you will but I thought it a good reminder, it usually is. Here's a great explanation on it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/130323/1068167

Comment: Are you actually connecting to the database or have you removed that from the snippet above?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Nice [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) holes... enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
mysql_query("UPDATE about SET `text` = '$row['text']'");
```

to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE about SET `text` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."'");
```

Also, try to move to mysqli or PDO..

Comment: Ok, so i should replace all $row['text'] to $_POST['text']?
and by security issues, should one use htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string` when you are putting user content into MySQL database. Use `htmlspecialchars` if you are echoing user content within an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Your update query should look like:

```
mysql_query("update `about` set `text`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try following code.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE about SET `text` = '$_POST['text']' WHERE DBid='dbid'");
```

DBid is your data base table primary id.